# Are there universal facial expressions for asking questions?

Tags: emotion, language

"Dog."
"Dog!"
"Dog?"
We know the first is a statement. The second a warning maybe. And the third a question.

Like facial expressions for emotions. Are there universal human facial expressions or voice modulations that show when we are asking a question? Or naming something. Or giving a warning. I imagine being able to distinguish these 3 things would be quite important for our ape-like ancestors.

In fact, do we share these with apes? When we try and teach apes words do we use things like pointing and intonation? Can they understand this?

Comment: The existence of universal facial and vocal expressions for emotions is highly controversial.  The likelihood of a universal facial or vocal expression for asking questions is even less likely I'd imagine.

Comment: You started asking about facial expressions then added voice modulations which is a different kind of language cue.  Voice modulation patterns can vary with different languages and cultures, and I am not sure but I believe the same applies to facial expressions.